# Objective-C: Is it bad practice to use dot notation inside of a message?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I couldn't find a similar question so I decided to ask it (this may be more appropriately asked on Programmers, if so I apologize in advance).

Is it bad practice to use dot notation along with a message call, like so:

```
[self.view addSubView:otherView];
```

As opposed to:

```
[[self view] addSubView:otherView];
```

I was just curious, it looked a tad bit strange but I don't see anything wrong with it. I'm still relatively new to Objective-C and am not familiar with any best practices of note yet.

Comment: No, that's fairly standard practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it. It's merely a stylistic question. Use whichever one you prefer. (The dot notation, by the way, has the **advantage** that the compiler throws an error if you're calling an undeclared property getter or setter with the dot notation, so you can potentially get rid of some strange run-time errors at compile time.)

Comment: Thanks, selected this one because of the tidbit about catching potential errors earlier.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bad practice at all. But it is just a **convention**.

Whatever you feel good you can use.

**What ever make your code readable you should use that.**

like :

```
employee.name.address.city.zip
```

<strike>will look like something as:</strike>

```
[employee [name [address [city zip]]]]
```

Even i did mistake above. So its your readability.

Actually it should be as :

```
[[[[employee name] address] city] zip]
```

**Also**, methods taking parameters can not be used with dot notation, you need to use bracket.

```
double amount=[self calculateInterestOnPrincipal:10000 rate:5.5 year:6]
```

Comment: I think you may have your brackets in reverse, shouldn't that be `[[[[employee name] address] city] zip]`?

Comment: If readability is a concern, then the dot notation is preferred. Also, pay attention to the syntax error you have in your example.

Comment: @izuriel and H2CO3, hows now?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use dot notation to get and set objects' state. That means, you should use dot notation for property objects. As you did is alright.
On the other hand, bracket notation is used to invoke objects' behavior, like

```
[self createSubviewWithFrame:_frame];
```